# onUpgrade | Android Studio error

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

Hola buenas tardes estoy programando un catalogo de clientes con SQLite y me marca este error en mi código el cual dice : error: ***mibd is not abstract and does not override abstract method onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase,int,int) in SQLiteOpenHelper***

pero ademas marca un error en la siguiente consulta del onUpgrade:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "  + TABLA_CLIENTES);
```

especificamente en el "EXISTS"

alguien sabe que puede ser?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cesar, recuerda que es mejor agregar el código a tus preguntas como texto en lugar de imagen, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La variable `TABLA_CLIENTES` en realidad contiene un Script para crear la tabla, te sugiero crear otra variable con el nombre de la tabla:

```
private static final String NOMBRE_TABLA = "CLIENTES";
```

y usarla en el método onUpgrade() :

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NOMBRE_TABLA);
    onCreate(db);
    //db.execSQL(TABLA_CLIENTES);
}
```